# How to assign 2d images to planes of a 3d OpenCV Mat, then extract 2D Mats along a different axis?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to make a 3D Mat out of stacked 2D Mats and then pull out 2D Mats along a different axis of the 3D Mat.  I know I can build this up manually accessing every row or col of every image but is there a better to do it like the following?

```
vector<cv::Mat> images;
```

... populate vector with images

```
int sz[] = {images[0].rows, images[0].cols, images.size()}
cv::Mat cube(3, sz, images[0].type() );
cube = Scalar(0);

for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
```

... place images into 3d mat

```
}

vector<cv::Mat> image_rows;

for (int i = 0; i < images[0].rows(); i++) {
```

... push image planes into image_rows along width and depth of 3D cube matrix

```
}
```

Comment: Have you seen what `cv::reshape` does? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-reshape

Comment: It seems like the operation of reshape would be ambiguous on a 3D mat given the parameters it takes- or do I make an n-channel image with each channel being one of the source 2d mats?  I do notice the 2.2.0 docs say 2D mats only but that is removed from the link you have (which is probably 2.3.0).

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of work with opencv and as far as I know that is the best way to do it. You could make a Mat of higher dimensional vectors but then your access would be even less clean. Stick to the vector its your best bet.