# Initialize 3D complex-value matrix in OpenCV

Tags: arrays, opencv

I tried the following code to initialize, but it doesn't work.

```
int size[] = {2,3,2};
Mat matA;
matA.create(3, size, CV_32FC2,Scalar::all(0));
```

Would you tell me what the correct way is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459131/how-to-assign-2d-images-to-planes-of-a-3d-opencv-mat-then-extract-2d-mats-along